# Possible to search and hold text in defined area of page in Acrobat by Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I have a script that uses the methods:
this.getPageNthWord and this.getPageNumWords, I have it search the whole page for a zip code and then hold that value, is it possible to define a smaller area than the whole page for the script to search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crop the page, do your search, then uncrop.

You crop by setting the "crop" pagebox.

Comment: You are a genius Max.